# On HTC One X, light sensor won't work when screen is off

Tags: android, sensors

I have a code that listens to light sensor changes and reads its value:

```
SensorManager sensorManager  = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
mLightSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);

//light sensor listener
private SensorEventListener lightSensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener(){

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //my reading code
    }
```

This simple code segment works fine on Nexus S, Nexus One and Galaxy Nexus, no matter the screen is on or off.

But when running on HTC One X, I found that it won't work when the screen is turned off. i.e. The sensor seems is not triggered when screen is off. But when screen is on, it works fine and gives correct readings.

Wondering if it's a hardware problem so that there is nothing I can do about it. Or it's just a setting issue? I've already turned automatic brightness on in the Setting, but it didn't help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement for sensors to work with the screen off. Since the light sensor is typically used to adjust screen brightness it could be reasonable for a device maker to not enable it with the screen off.

That said, try grabbing a partial wake lock which is the way to get sensors to work with the screen off (at least for the accelerometer):

```
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock lock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Light sensor");
    wl.acquire();
```

Make sure you get the wake lock permission:

And make sure to release the wake lock when you are done with it.